# While stops running in a Dynamicmodule

Tags: dynamic

I made this:

```
DynamicModule[{pne = {0, 0}, ido = 0, a = {0, -0.40}, pr = 200, 
  dt = 0.1, pn = {0, 0}, vne = {0, 0}, vn, stop = 11}, 
  ClickPane[
    Framed @ 
      Graphics[{
        Orange, Dynamic @ Disk[pne, 4], 
        Green, Dynamic @ Arrow[{pne, (pne + vne)*1.5}]}, 
        PlotRange -> pr],
    With[{w = 1/5*(pne - MousePosition["Graphics"])}, 
      ido = 0;
      While[stop > 10,
        ido = ido + 1;
        vne = If[ido < 2, w + a*dt, vn + a*dt];
        pne = If[ido < 2, pne + w*dt, pn + vne*dt];
        If[pne[[2]] < -195, vne = (vne - Normalize[vne]/2)*{1, -1}];
        If[pne[[2]] > 195, vne = (vne - Normalize[vne]/2)*{1, -1}];
        If[pne[[1]] < -195, vne = (vne - Normalize[vne]/2)*{-1, 1}];
        If[pne[[1]] > 195, vne = (vne - Normalize[vne]/2)*{-1, 1}];
        vn = vne;
        pn = pne;
        stop = 1/2 Norm[vne]^2 + (pne[[2]] + 195)*0.4;
        Pause[.001]; FinishDynamic[]]] &]]
```

I've noticed, the `While` stops running after around 450 loops.

I can't figure it out what's the cause. Any help would be nice because I'm a beginner.

Comment: I haven't tried the code, but [Dynamic evaluations will stop after a fixed amount of time](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DynamicEvaluationTimeout.html).

Comment: @Szabolcs  It times out just short of 6 seconds.

Comment: In addition to what @Szabolcs has said, [Slow Evaluations inside Dynamic](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/IntroductionToDynamic.html#962859965)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By measuring the time with the difference in `AbsoluteTime` from the beginning to the end of the `While`, I found it to be just less than 6 seconds.  To increase this time, use at the beginning of the notebook, for instance,

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, DynamicEvaluationTimeout -> 60]
```

which will run for several thousand steps.  My thanks to Szabolcs for the reference.

Internal progress of the `DynamicModule` can be tracked by placing `t0 = AbsoluteTime[];` immediately before `While`, `Dynamic[x, x = {AbsoluteTime[] - t0, ido, stop}];` immediately before `Pause`, and

```
Dynamic[x]
```

outside the `DynamicModule`.

(Note: In an earlier **Update**, I stated that the code would stop responding after six seconds.  However, I resolved this issue by restarting Mathematica, and it has not recurred.)